# characterizations of singular measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, total-variation

If $\nu$ and $\mu$ are finite and positive measures then $\nu \perp \mu$ if and only if $\|\nu - \mu \|= \|\nu\| + \|\mu \|$

Here, $\nu \perp \mu$ means that $\nu$ and  $\mu$ are singular measures, and the total variation $\| \nu \|$ is defined as $|\nu |(E) = \sup \{ |\nu(A)| +|\nu (B)|: A, B \quad \text{disjoint}, A \cup B \subset E \}$.

My work:
Suppose $\nu \perp \mu$, then there exist $A, \; B$ such that $A\cup B=X$ and $A\cap B =\phi$ with $\nu(E)=\nu(E\cap A)$ and $\mu(E)=\mu(E\cap B)$ for every $E$.
So,

\begin{align}
\|\nu - \mu\| & = |\nu -\mu|(X) = |\nu -\mu |(A \cup B) \\[8pt]
& = \sup \{ |(\nu -\mu)(A)|+|(\nu -\mu)(B)| \}  \\[8pt]
&= \sup \{ \nu(A)+\mu(B) \} \\[8pt]
& = \sup \{ |\nu(A)|\} + \sup \{|\mu(B)| \} \\[8pt]
& = \sup \{ |\nu(A)|+|\nu(B)|\} + \sup \{|\mu(A)|+|\mu(B)| \} \\[8pt]
& =|\nu|(X)+|\mu|(X)=\|\nu\|+\|\mu\|.
\end{align}

Is that correct and complete argument for the direct direction? and how can I prove the converse direction??

Comment: If you are defining $A,B$ to be certain sets that come out of the definition of singular measures, then you should use different names for the sets in the supremum when using the definition of total variation. You are conflating the two, and it is not clear how several of the steps you take are justified.

Comment: @angryavian, yes, you are right! I will update that. But, any idea how to show the other direction? by contradiction?

Comment: if $\mu(A), \mu(B) > 0 $ for any $A, B$ disjoint union to $X$ and likewise for $\nu$, then $|\nu - \mu|(A) < \mu(A) + \nu(A)$ ... Derive a contradiction.